# How to make a print.exe which you can access through the cmd and takes parameters in c

Tags: c, cmd, argv, argc

I have this c program right here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;
    int forparam = sizeof(argv);
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (i = 1; i < forparam; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                printf("%s", argv[i]);
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                printf(" %s", argv[i]);
            }
        }   
    }
    else {
        printf("One argument expected\n");
    }
    
}
```

You type the name of the file in the Win10 cmd and a parameter and it prints out the parameter onto the cmd. At least that's what it's supposed to do. It can't take up more than 3 parameters and if you enter 1 or 2 parameters then it prints them out but with a "(null)" in the end. How can I make it to work? Because a space indicates another parameter it ignores it that's why I need all this code. Your help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(argv)` gives you the size in bytes of the `argv` pointer object, not the number of elements it points to.

`argc` gives you the number of parameters on the command line, where `argv[0]` is the command used to invoke the program:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  printf( "Command used to invoke program: %s\n", argv[0] );
  for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    printf( "parameter %d: %s\n", i, argv[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `forparam`, you have everything you need with `argc`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                printf("%s", argv[i]);
            } else if (i > 1) {
                printf(" %s", argv[i]);
            }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        printf("One argument expected\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
}
```

Moreover, `sizeof argv` returns the size of the pointer `argv`, not the number of elements in `argv` (which is not known to the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `sizeof(argv)` is computed at compile-time, and is maybe 4 (bytes) or probably 8 (bytes). I suppose it is 8.

Then your `for` loop is executed with `i=1`, then with `i=2` up to `i=7`

You probably want `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)`

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) for more.

Take inspiration from the C source code of existing [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), in particular [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).